# Alternating projections on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P_1, P_2$ be the orthoprojections onto $S_1, S_2$, closed subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$. It is straightforward to show that if $(P_1P_2)^nx \to z$ then $z \in S_1 \cap S_2$ (I can post a quick proof if anyone wants it). But under what conditions on $P_1$ and $P_2$ or $x$ does $(P_1P_2)^nx$ converges at all?

Comment: I'd say it always converge: If it keeps bouncing from $S_1$ to $S_2$ and back it'll converge to $0$ because it'll have its norm reduced every time. But that's just an intuition from looking at what happens in the plane with two lines.

Comment: @xavierm02 The plane is finite dimensional so there's strong element of compactness, which is not present in the infinite-dimensional case. I'm sure that would give drastically different results but I don't know how.

Comment: Let's say you have a basis. Then your element is a linear combinaison of a finite number of elements of the basis. So if $P_1P_2(S)\subseteq S$ where $S$ is the subspace spanned by that finite number of elements, then we're back to the finite dimensional case. And I can't find an example where it isn't the case. Can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can prove strong convergence following this article:

> The product of projection operators
>
> I. Halperin
>
> http://acta.fyx.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=7164&dataObjectType=article

The original result is due to Neumann. Halperin's note generalizes this to $m$ projections:

There it is proven that $(P_1P_2\dots P_m)^n x \to z$ with $z$ being the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S_1\cap S_2\cap \dots \cap S_m$.

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks for the link.